# creating method in new class; cannot find symbol error in main class

Tags: java, methods

I know this has probably been an error asked about a million times but I'm really struggling to understand why I'm getting this with my one specific assignment.

I am to create a method class that will go through a String[] of words called 'list' and sort them alphabetically. I thought this would be an easy..

Here is what I have, I have no problem with the actual sorting, I just can't get Java to understand that I'm trying to call the method. I was given a specific class name, main class code, and method header, so I cannot change it or else I can't use the code runner.

```
class Lesson_15_Activity{

  public static void sortAndPrint(String [] list){ //cant change
    for (int pos = 0; pos < list.length-1; pos++){
      for (int k = 0; k <= pos; k++){ //
        if (list[k].compareTo(list[pos]) < 0){
          list[pos] = list[k];
        }
      }
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < list.length-1; a++){
      System.out.println(list[a]);
    }
  }
}

//the main method 

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] list = { "against" , "forms" , "belief" , "government" , "democratic" , "movement" , "understanding"};
    sortAndPrint(list);
  //^this is where i get the error
  }
}
```

I've tried adding code like this like in my earlier lessons but couldn't get it to work.

```
private String[] words;

public setWords(){
    words = list;
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: call : Lesson_15_Activity.sortAndPrint(list);

Answer (score 0):

You can go straight forward like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Lesson15Activity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = {"against", "forms", "belief", "government", "democratic", "movement", "understanding"};
        sortAndPrint(list);
        //^this is where i get the error
    }

    public static void sortAndPrint(String[] list) { //cant change
        Arrays.stream(list).sorted().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define two classes: `Lesson_15_Activity` and `Main`, and you're trying to use the method `sortAndPrint` since the class `Main`, when it is defined in `Lesson_15_Activity`.

One simple solution is join both classes:

```
class Lesson_15_Activity{

      public static void sortAndPrint(String [] list){ //cant change
        for (int pos = 0; pos < list.length-1; pos++){
          for (int k = 0; k <= pos; k++){ //
            if (list[k].compareTo(list[pos]) < 0){
              list[pos] = list[k];
            }
          }
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < list.length-1; a++){
          System.out.println(list[a]);
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] list = { "against" , "forms" , "belief" , "government" , "democratic" , "movement" , "understanding"};
        sortAndPrint(list);
      //^this is where i get the error
      }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think this is working since I do not get a compilation error in the code runner, but now repl.it (I need to manually install dr java later since it won't install as usual and I'm trying to catch up in class) is still giving me the error. Should I just ditch the online environment and get a real IDE?

Comment: Yes, you need a real IDE

Comment: Always get a decent IDE. Okay, it's possible to write Java code in notepad, but it is also possible to dig a reservoir with a teaspoon.